# How can I create an array of subnets on an existing vnet using Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

In my bicep file I obtain a reference to the existing vnet like this:

```
resource existingVNET 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: 'the-existing-vnet'
}
```

I have tried to include multiple (four to be exact) resource statements for each of the subnets like this:

```
resource subnetPbdResource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2020-11-01' = {
  parent: existingVNET
  name: 'first-snet'
  ...
}
resource subnetPbdResource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2020-11-01' = {
  parent: existingVNET
  name: 'second-snet'
  ...
}
```

...however, when I run this (using `az deployment group create ...`) I get an error: with code `AnotherOperationInProgress`. One random (it seems) subnet has been created under the vnet.

I've also tried to define an array of subnets like this:

```
var subnets = [
  {
    name: 'api'
    subnetPrefix: '10.144.0.0/24'
  }
  {
    name: 'worker'
    subnetPrefix: '10.144.1.0/24'
  }
]
```

...but I cannot find a way to assign the existing vnet with the subnets array. `.properties.subnets` is not accessible for the existing vnet resource it seems.

Any tip appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got a great answer on [Bicep github discussion](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/3449)

Basically it boils down to building an array of subnets, use @batchSize(1) to ensure serial creation of subnets (I guess this achieves the same as using `dependsOn` in answer from @Manuel Batsching) and pass the subnet array as parameter to `Resource` "create subnet statement".
Obvious advantage: no duplicate code to create subnet

Answer (score 3):

It seems that ARM gets tangled up when it tries to deploy more than one subnet resource at the same time.

You can use `dependsOn` to make sure the subnets get created one after another:

```
resource existingVNET 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: 'the-existing-vnet'
}

resource subnetPbdResource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'first-snet'
  parent: existingVNET
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.1.0/24'
  }
}

resource subnetPbdResource2 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'second-snet'
  parent: existingVNET
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.2.0/24'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    subnetPbdResource
  ]
}

resource subnetPbdResource3 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'third-snet'
  parent: existingVNET
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.3.0/24'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    subnetPbdResource2
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, how do you define scope here?